# Bucketed joins in PySpark/Iceberg

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-iceberg, bucketing

I'm trying to perform a join between two tables in PySpark using the iceberg format. I'm trying to use bucketing to improve performance, and avoid a shuffle, but it appears to be having no effect whatsoever. What might I be missing?

**Code for non-bucketed join:**

```
db = "ml_recommendations" 
col = "id" 

df1 = spark.range(1, 10 ** 6)  # This will create a DF with a single col "id"
df1.writeTo(f"{db}.no_bucket_table1") \ 
    .using('iceberg') \
    .option("fanout-enabled", "true") \
    .createOrReplace() 

df2 = spark.range(1, 10 ** 5)  # This will create a DF with a single col "id"
df2.writeTo(f"{db}.no_bucket_table2") \ 
    .using('iceberg') \ 
    .option("fanout-enabled", "true") \ 
    .createOrReplace() 

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1) 

df = spark.sql( 
    f"select * from {db}.no_bucket_table1 t1 " 
    f"inner join {db}.no_bucket_table2 t2 " 
    f"on t1.{col}=t2.{col}" 
) 
df.explain(extended=True)
```

Result of the non-bucketed join:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join Inner, (id#8L = id#9L)
:- Filter isnotnull(id#8L)
:  +- RelationV2[id#8L] Iceberg iceberg.ml_recommendations.no_bucket_table1
+- Filter isnotnull(id#9L)
   +- RelationV2[id#9L] Iceberg iceberg.ml_recommendations.no_bucket_table2
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- SortMergeJoin [id#8L], [id#9L], Inner
   :- Sort [id#8L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- **Exchange hashpartitioning**(id#8L, 400), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=201]
   :     +- Filter isnotnull(id#8L)
   :        +- BatchScan[id#8L] iceberg.ml_recommendations.no_bucket_table1 (branch=null) [filters=id IS NOT NULL, groupedBy=] RuntimeFilters: []
   +- Sort [id#9L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- **Exchange hashpartitioning**(id#9L, 400), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=202]
         +- Filter isnotnull(id#9L)
            +- BatchScan[id#9L] iceberg.ml_recommendations.no_bucket_table2 (branch=null) [filters=id IS NOT NULL, groupedBy=] RuntimeFilters: []
```

**Code for the bucketed join:**

```
df1 = spark.range(1, 10 ** 6)  # This will create a DF with a single col "id"
df1.writeTo(f"{db}.bucket_table1") \ 
    .using('iceberg') \ 
    .option("fanout-enabled", "true") \ 
    .partitionedBy(pf.bucket(100, "id")) \ 
    .createOrReplace() 

df2 = spark.range(1, 10 ** 5)  # This will create a DF with a single col "id"
df2.writeTo(f"{db}.bucket_table2") \ 
    .using('iceberg') \ 
    .option("fanout-enabled", "true") \ 
    .partitionedBy(pf.bucket(100, "id")) \ 
    .createOrReplace() 

df = spark.sql( 
    f"select * from {db}.bucket_table1 t1 " 
    f"inner join {db}.bucket_table2 t2 " 
    f"on t1.{col}=t2.{col}" 
) 
df.explain(extended=True)
```

Result of the bucketed join

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join Inner, (id#43L = id#44L)
:- Filter isnotnull(id#43L)
:  +- RelationV2[id#43L] Iceberg iceberg.ml_recommendations.bucket_table1
+- Filter isnotnull(id#44L)
   +- RelationV2[id#44L] Iceberg iceberg.ml_recommendations.bucket_table2
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- SortMergeJoin [id#43L], [id#44L], Inner
   :- Sort [id#43L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- **Exchange hashpartitioning**(id#43L, 400), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=422]
   :     +- Filter isnotnull(id#43L)
   :        +- BatchScan[id#43L] iceberg.ml_recommendations.bucket_table1 (branch=null) [filters=id IS NOT NULL, groupedBy=] RuntimeFilters: []
   +- Sort [id#44L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- **Exchange hashpartitioning**(id#44L, 400), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=423]
         +- Filter isnotnull(id#44L)
            +- BatchScan[id#44L] iceberg.ml_recommendations.bucket_table2 (branch=null) [filters=id IS NOT NULL, groupedBy=] RuntimeFilters: []
```

So the question is - why is bucketing not removing the exchange step?

Comment: Problem is that Spark is not MPP so you're not going to get that much performance gain.  Easiest is to use an MPP OLAP database like StarRocks that can read and write into Iceberg.

Comment: What is the Spark version you are trying to get this working?